# Check switchChange but only on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I triggered the code below **only** if one of the checkboxes/switches are changed by a **mouse click**.
Right now the code is also triggered if a script is changing the state of one of the switches.

```
$('input:checkbox').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state)
{
  if (state == true) 
   {
     var id, switch;
     id = ($(this).attr('id'));
     switch = "ON";
   }
   else
   {
     var id, switch;
     id = ($(this).attr('id'));
     switch = "OFF"
   }
});
```

Comment: It depends on how the code change the state of switches. Try this:
$('input:checkbox').click(function (event, state) { .... })

Comment: Set `click` event on input (if not visible: on part that is visible), then it will trigger *only* on click